# Scala - Spark : Operate on all the columns of DF at once and create a case-class for each column efficiently

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am facing a DataFrame with more than 50,000 rows, and around 30-100 columns.
The data is numeric, and I wish to 'create' for each column a case-class with these attributes:

- max value
- min value
- standard deviation

and save this data structure to a Map (col_name -> ColData case-class).

I will work with this toy-example to demonstrate:

```scala
// The desired case-class & desired map:
case class ColData(name: String, min: Double, max: Double, std_dev: Double) {}
var columnsData: Map[String, ColData] = Map.empty


// The toy example:
val df = Seq(
         (1, 20, 30, 4),
         (2, 30, 40, 5),
         (3, 10, 30, 2)
       ).toDF("col0", "col1", "col2", "col3")

+----+----+----+----+
|col0|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+----+
|   1|  20|  30|   4|
|   2|  30|  40|   5|
|   3|  10|  30|   2|
+----+----+----+----+
```

1. that approach have already been tried:

```scala
df.columns.foreach(c => {
    var (min_c, max_c, std_dev_c) = df.select(min(c), max(c), stddev(c)).as[(Double, Double, Double)].first()
    columnsData = columnsData + (c -> ColData(c, min_c, max_c, std_dev_c))
})
```

But I experience it is slow and inefficient.

2. I thought of that approach (that suppose to iterate over the DF less times) but could not tell if it is any better:

```scala
val min_cols = df.select(cols.map(min):_*).first().toSeq.toArray.map(_.toString.toDouble)
val max_cols = df.select(cols.map(max):_*).first().toSeq.toArray.map(_.toString.toDouble)
val std_cols = df.select(cols.map(stddev):_*).first().toSeq.toArray.map(_.toString.toDouble)

var seq = Seq(min_cols, max_cols, std_cols).transpose

df.columns.foreach(c => {
    var chosen = seq(df.columns.indexOf(c))
    var (min, max, std_dev) = (chosen(0), chosen(1), chosen(2))
    columnsData = columnsData + (c -> ColData(c, min, max, std_dev))
})
```

**My questions**:

1. Are there any other ways to do it fast and efficient?
2. Should I use cache / persist (before) & unpersist (after) to improve the performance? how should it be done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach is inefficient because you end up traversing your data frame multiple times (as many times as you have columns). Second one is a bit better, but still does three traversals.

Why not do everything in a single scan?

```
   df.select(
      df.columns.flatMap { c => Seq(min(c), max(c), stddev(c)) } :_*
   ).first
    .toSeq
    .grouped(3)
    .zip(df.columns.iterator)
    .collect { case (Seq(min: Number, max: Number, stddev: Number), col) => 
       col -> ColData(col, min.doubleValue, max.doubleValue, stddev.doubleValue) 
    }.toMap
```

Comment: Thank you, looks good and works well!
Should I use `cache()` before and `unpersist()` after?
Also, is there any advantage of using `collect()` over `first`, and `df.agg` over `df.select`?

Comment: There's nothing to cache here, that would be just pure waste. `collect` is the same as `first` in this case because there is only one row anyway, `first` is just a bit more convenient, because after `collect` you'd need `head` to get the actual row. `agg` is the same as `select` in this case too, because there is no grouping (I didn't even know agg actually existed on ungrouped dataframes).